# Using Ubuntu 13.10 Live USB "an operating system not found" error

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have a Dell that is a few years old, trying to install Ubuntu on it just for something new to try.  The computer currently has windows 7, which will boot and run fine, but I'd like to wipe the whole thing and just use Ubuntu.

I have created a live USB, and I know it works because I can actually run Ubuntu off the USB on my other laptop.  When I try to run it on my dell, however, all that comes up is "an operating system wasn't found.  Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system."

I am a complete newbie to this, so I have no idea what is wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reasons for "Operating system Not found" Error while booting from live USB:

- Check the software did you used to create a bootable ubuntu live disk on Windows.

See [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) page or install Unetbootin to create a Ubuntu live USB on windows.

- Check the md5sum of the downloaded Ubuntu.iso file.If it not matches then redownload the iso file.
- Check the boot-order in bios and make sure to set it to boot from live-usb.

Comment: Ah, I re-burned my USB using Unetbootin rather than my simple ISO to USB program, and it seems to be working now.  Haven't installed yet, but I am at least running off the live USB.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Just had this issue.  ISO to USB did NOT work.  Unetbootin worked.